# How can I create NodeList?

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I have got `<p>` tags that exists in a page by using `document.getElementsByTagName('p')`.
What I want is, adds these tags in nodeList, like as do `document.querySelectorAll`.

**For example:**
Suppose if we have 4 `<p>` tags exists in a page.
I want to add the 4 tags to be as nodeList.

**I have made the following code:**

```
var elem = null, nodList = document.createDocumentFragment(), i;
elem = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
    nodList.appendChild(elem[i]);
}
```

But unfortunate, does not work fine and in particular in `IE 6 ,7` browsers.

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a "live" collection of elements. You are modifying the DOM inside of your loop and the underlying "live" collection is changing as well (see [MDN getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)).   Alternatively, use two loops one to build an array of the elements to be added to your nodeList and a second to append them to your nodeList.